# Backbone 0.9.2 view initialize not being called

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I am new to Backbone.js. I am using CoffeScript on a v0.9.2 app. The app works "fine" but the `initialize()` method of the views is not being called. Events are not being properly binded either. I am trying to figure out why this is not the case. I am using other (manual) ways to bind events to elements but that should not be the case.

The app is instantiated with this:

```coffeescript
window.Site =
  Models: {}
  Collections: {}
  Views: {}
  Routers: {}
  init: -> 
    new Site.Routers.MyRouter()
    Backbone.history.start()

$(document).ready ->
  Site.init()
```

The router:

```coffeescript
class Site.Routers.MyRouter extends Backbone.Router
    routes:
        '': 'index'

    initialize: ->
        # some code here (this IS being called)

    index: =>
        # this is also being called since I am trying mysite.com/
        view = new Site.Views.MyView()
        $('#someId').html(view.render().el)
```

The view:

```coffeescript
class Site.Views.MyView extends Backbone.View

    template: JST['views/index']

    events:
        'click .someElement': 'someMethod'

    inititalize: ->
        console.log "hello" # NOT CALLED
        _.bindAll @
        @

    render: =>
        # draw stuff (this works)
        @
```

The view gets drawn fine. Why is `initialize` not being called?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to spell `initialize` correctly =p

```
inititalize: -> # should be `initialize: ->`
  console.log "hello" # NOT CALLED
```

Comment: Well played @CaseyFoster.  Well played. +1

Comment: oh boy this is so embarrasing! i'm glad i actually copy/pasted the code from my app and edited in the questions or this would have never appeared! since i copy/pasted the first view into the other views this bug started crawling its way into my app... sigh... i swear i've been looking at this code for so long...

Comment: Hahaha, I too needed Stackoverflow to have my spelling corrected :)

Answer (score 2):

For future readers, also check you don't have two initialize functions.

```
Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    // not called 
  },

  // stuff

  initialize: function () {
    // overwrites previous
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't write CoffeeScript, but  the only place I see an instance of your view initailized is in the router:

```
index: =>
     view = new Site.Views.MyView()
```

I suspect the router's index is not being called and as a result your view's initialize isn't being called.   Extending a view doesn't create an instance of the view, rather it creates a customized definition of a view.

HTH.

Comment: hi... thanks for the input... I added a comment in the code clarifying that the index of the router is being called since I am visiting `/`... if creating the view that way does not create an instance of the view, what would be the proper way to do it? I am basing my app on this example http://railscasts.com/episodes/323-backbone-on-rails-part-1